# Bug in privileges and badges links in stackexchange.com pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stackexchange.com, achievements-dialog

I noticed that on https://stackexchange.com pages the links "privileges" and "badges" are displayed:

[image: top bar button]

If click in privileges or badges I'm directed to 404 pages:

[image: 404 page]

I believe these links never existed, so it would be interesting to remove them or create pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the report! The links will be hidden on stackexchange.com starting with the next build.

Comment: How about returning such links for `anysite.stackexchange.com`?

Comment: @alexolut They'll be there when the new top bar is enabled network-wide.