# The help link in stackexchange.com redirect to page not found

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, stack-exchange-button

The ["help"](https://stackexchange.com/help) link in the https://stackexchange.com dropdownlist is redirect to "**Page Not Found**" page

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Help Link]

Comment: Seems to be identical to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301264/bug-in-privileges-and-badges-links-in-stackexchange-com-pages) but on a different menu.